# Emails not working after changing A record

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, dns-zone

My domain name is example.com. I have a dedicated server with WHM. Last year, I had created hostnames on the dedicated server as ns1.example.com & ns2.example.com. I used the same dedicated server for hosting as well as emails. My mx record was example.com itself.

Now, I have renewed my website and hosted on AWS. I just changed the A record to point example.com to the IP address provided by AWS. But, my emails are still on the dedicated server. After changing my A record, my emails have stopped working.

How can I solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a MX record pointing at the email server.

Here's an example of my server, with DNS on CloudFlare. I have AWS handling web and FastMail handling email.

[image: MX record setup]